# React Native Border Radius with background color

Tags: javascript, styles, react-native

In React Native, `borderRadius` is working but the background color given to the button stays a square. What is going on here?

JS

```
<TouchableHighlight
  style={styles.submit}
  onPress={() => this.submitSuggestion(this.props)}
  underlayColor='#fff'>
    <Text style={[this.getFontSize(),styles.submitText]}>Submit</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Style

```
...
submit:{
    marginRight:40,
    marginLeft:40,
    marginTop:10,
},
submitText:{
    paddingTop:20,
    paddingBottom:20,
    color:'#fff',
    textAlign:'center',
    backgroundColor:'#68a0cf',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#fff'
},
...
```

[image]

Comment: just a guess, try to give `borderStyle: 'solid'` to the `submitText`

Comment: No, that didnt work unfortunately

Comment: on which environment you're testing? ios or android?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Try moving the button styling to the `TouchableHighlight` itself:

**Styles:**

```
submit: {
  marginRight: 40,
  marginLeft: 40,
  marginTop: 10,
  paddingTop: 20,
  paddingBottom: 20,
  backgroundColor: '#68a0cf',
  borderRadius: 10,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: '#fff',
},
submitText: {
  color: '#fff',
  textAlign: 'center',
}
```

**Button (same):**

```
<TouchableHighlight
  style={styles.submit}
  onPress={() => this.submitSuggestion(this.props)}
  underlayColor='#fff'>
    <Text style={[this.getFontSize(),styles.submitText]}>Submit</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

[image]

Answer (score 131):

You should add `overflow: hidden` to your styles:

Js:

```
<Button style={styles.submit}>Submit</Button>
```

Styles:

```
submit {
   backgroundColor: '#68a0cf';
   overflow: 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: `overflow: 'hidden'` worked for me even without react-native-button

Comment: Thanks. Yes, putting the `backgroundColor` and `borderRadius` on the container, then adding `overflow: 'hidden'` to the container worked for me. (Also not using `react-native-button`.)

Comment: this is what I wanted ! (not the checked one)

Comment: overflow: 'hidden' solved my problem ❤️

Answer (score 8):

Never give borderRadius to your `<Text />` always wrap that `<Text />` inside your `<View />` or in your `<TouchableOpacity/>`.

**borderRadius on `<Text />` will work perfectly on Android devices. But on IOS devices it won't work.**

So keep this in your practice to wrap your `<Text/>` inside your `<View/>` or on `<TouchableOpacity/>` and then give the borderRadius to that `<View />` or `<TouchableOpacity />`  so that it will work on both Android as well as on IOS devices.

For example:-

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{borderRadius: 15}}>
   <Text>Button Text</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 8):

**Remember**
if you want to give Text a backgroundcolor and then also borderRadius in that case also write overflow:'hidden' your text having a background colour will also get the radius otherwise it's impossible to achieve until unless you wrap it with View and give backgroundcolor and radius to it.

```
<Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', color:'white', borderRadius:10, overflow:'hidden'}}>Dummy</Text>
```

Comment: `overflow:'hidden'` is enough!

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it by updating:

```
touchable: {
  borderWidth: 0.2;
  ...
};
```

to be

```
touchable: {
  borderWidth: 1;
  ...
};
```

Looks like decimal values(0.2) don't work with borderWidth on android

Answer (score 0):

Apply the below line of code :

```
<TextInput
  style={{ height: 40, width: "95%", borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 2, borderRadius: 20,  marginBottom: 20, fontSize: 18, backgroundColor: '#68a0cf' }}
  // Adding hint in TextInput using Placeholder option.
  placeholder=" Enter Your First Name"
  // Making the Under line Transparent.
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`borderRadius` will work on  for Android & iOS both devices, but below properties won't work in iOS devices:

```
borderTopLeftRadius, 
borderTopRightRadius, 
borderBottomLeftRadius,
borderBottomRightRadius
```

So you write your code always something like this:

Example 1: this will work perfectly for (iOS & Android) both devices

```
<View style={{borderTopRightRadius: 25, borderBottomLeftRadius: 25}}>
   <Text>Submit</Text>
</View>
```

Example 2: this will work for (iOS & Android) both devices

```
<Text style={{borderRadius: 25, overflow: 'hidden'}}>Submit</Text>
```

Example 3: this will won't work for iOS devices (for Android devices will work fine)

```
<Text style={{borderTopRightRadius: 25, borderBottomLeftRadius: 25}}>Submit</Text>
```